# How to move/copy a lot of files (not all files) in a directory?

Tags: linux, copy, command, move

I got a directory which contains approx 9000 files, the file names are in ascending number (however not necessarily consecutive).

Now I need to copy/move ~3000 files from number xxxx to number yyyy to another direcotory. How can I use cp or mv command for that purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `seq` utility to generate numbers for this kind of operation:

```
for i in `seq 4073 7843` ; do cp file_${i}_name.png /destination/folder ; done
```

On the downside, this will execute `cp` a lot more often than QuantumMechanic's solution; but QuantumMechanic's solution may not execute if the total length of all the filenames is greater than the kernel's `argv` size limitation (which could be between 128K and 2048K, depending upon your kernel version and stack-size rlimits; see `execve(2)` for details).

If the range you want spans orders of magnitudes (e.g., between `900` and `1010`) then the `seq -w` option may be useful, it zero-pads the output numbers.

Comment: Ah, duh. Good idea. You can use my echo foo | xargs cp -t to get around that.

Comment: Thanks! Most of the file names are in odd number so a lot of cp commands were unnecessary but I'm OK with that.

Answer (score 3):

```
find -type f | while read file; do if [ "$file" -ge xxxx -o "$file" -le yyyy ]; then echo $file; fi; done | xargs cp -t /destination/
```

If you want to limit to 3000 files, do:

```
export i=0; find -type f | while read file; do if [ "$file" -ge xxxx -o "$file" -le yyyy ]; then echo $file; let i+=1; fi; if [ $i -gt 3000 ]; then break; fi; done | xargs cp -t /destination/
```

If the files have a common suffix after the number, use ${file%%suffix} inside the if (you can use globs in the suffix).

Comment: `cpio -p` would be a better choice than `xargs cp` IMHO.

Comment: Yeah, but how would you move files? :P

Comment: Fair enough :) You're pretty much stuck with `xargs` for moving but I'd still go with `cpio -p` for copying.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most elegant, but how about something like:

```
cp 462[5-9] 46[3-9]? 4[7-9]?? 5??? 6[0-2]?? 63[0-4]? 635[0-3]  otherDirectory
```

which would copy files named 4625 to 6353 inclusive to `otherDirectory`.  (You wouldn't want to use something like `4*` since that would copy the file `4`, `42`, `483`, etc.)

Comment: Not at all!  Nicely demonstrates how to do more fine-grained matching.

Comment: I can't really read this answer. What is going on with these apparently random numbers?